# Одна часть текста двигается, а другая не реагирует

Tags: html, css

Почему `header__inner` подвинула ссылки `nav__link` вправо, а `header__logo` не двигает слово `ARCANE` при вводе тех же команд в css?

```css
/* HEADER*/

.header {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
}


/* HEADER__LOGO*/

.header__logo {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: royalblue;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.header__inner {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header__inner">
      <div class="header__logo">ARCANE</div>

      <nav class="nav">
        <a class="nav__link" href="#">CONTACT</a>
        <a class="nav__link" href="#">SERACH</a>
        <a class="nav__link" href="#">ABOUT</a>
      </nav>

    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.header {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.header__logo {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: royalblue;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.header__inner {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header__inner">
      <div class="header__logo">ARCANE</div>

      <nav class="nav">
        <a class="nav__link" href="#">CONTACT</a>
        <a class="nav__link" href="#">SERACH</a>
        <a class="nav__link" href="#">ABOUT</a>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

`nav__link` находяться с правой стороны - поскольку вы задали .header__inner своства флекс элемента `display: flex;justify-content: space-between;` по сути вправо прижимается их родитель - `.nav` /// У класса `.header__logo` не задана фиксируемая ширина и это блочный элемент, по этому он будет занимать все свободное простраство

Comment: Получается мне нужно div исправить на span и к ( .header__logo) дописать width?

Comment: Не понятно чего вы хотите достичь, но на вопрос почему так происходит я вам ответил. Так работает СSS. В представленном вами html css много синтаксических ошибок. Пока вы их не исправите он не запуститься. Или скопируйте мое представление

Comment: У меня слово ARCANE написано гораздо правее , нежели у вас. Как добиться перемещения слово Arcane не зависимо от других (элементов) слов на сайте?

Comment: Надо понимать где оно вам надо. Можете добавить родителю значения `position:relative;` а элементу со словом "position:absolute; top:10px; left:20px;" по тогда для .header__inner поставить `justify-content:flex-end;`